# dd_robot2.urdf help

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am reading "ROS ROBOTICS BY EXAMPLE SECOND EDITION " and I am stuck in chapter 2 , when it introduces the dd_robot2.urdf. What I am getting is the image blow
[image: C:\fakepath\robot.png]

but the book has this instead:
[image: C:\fakepath\Screenshot from 2018-02-02 20-25-48.png]

I followed the book step by step and I cant figure out where I went wrong. Any help?
Thank you!

EDIT1:

[image: C:\fakepath\Screenshot from 2018-02-02 22-44-55.png]

EDIT 2:

Launch File:

```
<launch>
   <!-- values passed by command line input -->     
   <arg name="model" />
   <arg name="gui" default="False" />

   <!-- set these parameters on Parameter Server -->
   <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find ros_robotics)/urdf/$(arg model)" />
   <param name="use_gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>

   <!-- Start 3 nodes: joint_state_publisher, robot_state_publisher and rviz -->
   <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />

   <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" />

   <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find ros_robotics)/urdf.rviz" required="true" />
   <!-- (required = "true") if rviz dies, entire roslaunch will be killed -->
</launch>
```

URDF File:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<robot name="dd_robot">

  <!-- Base Link -->
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
          <box size="0.5 0.5 0.25"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <!-- Right Wheel -->
  <link name="right_wheel">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.570795 0 0" />
      <geometry>
          <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.2" />
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <joint name="joint_right_wheel" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="right_wheel"/>
    <origin xyz="0 -0.30 0" rpy="0 0 0" /> 
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
  </joint>

  <!-- Left Wheel -->
  <link name="left_wheel">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.570795 0 0" />
      <geometry>
          <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.2" />
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <joint name="joint_left_wheel" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="left_wheel"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0.30 0" rpy="0 0 0" /> 
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
  </joint>

</robot>
```

Command on terminal:

```
$ roslaunch ros_robotics ddrobot_rviz.launch model:=dd_robot2.urdf
```

Edit3:

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281689/dd_robot2.urdf-help/) by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-02-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-03**:
RViz says that there's a tf problem. Can you update your question with a screen shot of your tf tree?

**Comment by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on 2018-02-03**:
It has been updated in Edit1 screenshot

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-03**:
That's a screen shot of RViz. I'm asking for your [tf tree](https://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf#Using_view_frames)

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-03**:
When I use your launch file (removing references to your `ros_robotics` package) everything loads fine and I can visualize the model just as in the book.

**Comment by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on 2018-02-04**:
strange my doesnt load up like that. Let me screen shot my TF tree.

**Comment by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on 2018-02-04**:
How do i run the TF Tree?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-04**:
It's in the tutorial I linked to in an earlier comment

**Comment by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on 2018-02-04**:
I updated it with screenshot seems not work when i used `rosrun tf view_frames`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-04**:
Your last edit seems to suggest that you're mixing different Python interpreters. Do you have Anaconda installed by any chance? Or Python 2 *and* 3?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-04**:
Also: **don't post screenshots of console text**. It's just text. Copy-paste it into your question and format it using the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-04**:
Do you get error msgs when starting the launch files at all? If `robot_state_publisher` or `static_transform_publisher` fail with the same error msgs as `view_frames`, that would explain your problems with RViz.

**Comment by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on 2018-02-04**:
Yes I do have Anaconda install and Python 3. Got it thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-04**:
For now: remove Anaconda and Python 3 from the `$PATH` and `$PYTHONPATH`. Then try again.

If it works, that's your problem.

If you want to continue using Anaconda, search for Anaconda related questions here on ROS Answers. There are many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you don't have a TF publisher running, or you don't have the right frame selected in rviz.

You should double-check your rviz settings and make sure the `robot_state_publisher` node is running to publish the TF transforms from your URDF.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on 2018-02-03**:
I tried that and still doesnt seem to work. I ran the robot_state_publisher node did not fix the issue. take a look at my EDIT 1: screen shot to see if I missed anything.
Thanks for your time

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-02-03**:
Your screenshot shows an rviz error "no TF data". Was robot_state_publisher still running when you took your screenshots?

**Comment by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on 2018-02-03**:
I got this message when i ran it:
: Shutdown request received.
: Reason given for shutdown: [new node registered with same name]

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-02-03**:
Do you have a launch file running that is running another copy of `robot_state_publisher` ? Nodes don't normally shut down like that unless there's another copy running somewhere.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-02-03**:
It seems like you've left some of the details out of your question. I'm not very familiar with the book you're using, and without all of the details about which other nodes you're running, it's difficult to help.

**Comment by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on 2018-02-03**:
I added the launch file and URDF code up at the top for you to take a look at if i am missing anything?
The book is called "ROS ROBOTICS BY EXAMPLE SECOND EDITION" by  Carol Fairchild, Dr. Thomas L. Harman